# Javascript SVG animation glitches between frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Hi I have done a jquery/svg/js animation to be run on multiple platforms:

http://jsfiddle.net/devdavid/GV5SK/2/

However there is a glitch in the animation between after "turn around" and walk there is a jump. Am i translating something erroneously?

The flow is controlled by a jquery slider and supposed to be move to the left if slider is to the left of your current position value. turn move to the right and turn back if it is to the right of your current position value...

<----Left

turn> ----right-->

See the fiddle above

The logic:

```
//States at startup:
var walkIndex = 0;
var position = 500;
var turnIndex = 0;
var scaleX=1;
var translationCompensationWalkX = 0;
var translationCompensationTurnX = 0;

//Init called by slider:
Element.prototype.walk=function (){
    walk();
    setTimeout(hideAll,100);
    clearInterval(walkTimeout);
    walkTimeout = setInterval(walk, 100);
}
function setTranslationCompensation(){
    if(directionToWalkLeft){
        translationCompensationWalkX = 0;
        translationCompensationTurnX = 0;
    }else{
        translationCompensationWalkX = 600;
        translationCompensationTurnX = 600;
    };

}

function translateImages(){
    //Move all images visible and hidden:
    $('#walkGroup').stop().animate({
        svgTransform: 'translate('+(translationCompensationWalkX+position)+',0) scale('+scaleX+',1)'
    },0);
    $('#soundWave').stop().animate({
        svgTransform: 'translate('+500/position+',0) scale('+(position)/500+',1)'
    },0);
}

function step(){
    //Increase step:
    if(directionToWalkLeft){
        position -= 20;
    }else{
        position+= 20;
    };
    //Switch to next image;
    $('#walk'+walkIndex).hide();
    walkIndex = (walkIndex+1)%25+1;
    $('#walk'+walkIndex).show();
}

function walk(){
    setTranslationCompensation();
    //Check if end position has been reached in left or right direction.
    if((position > endPoint && directionToWalkLeft) || (position < endPoint && !directionToWalkLeft) ){
        step();
        translateImages();


        //End position reached prepare for rotation if facing the right direction:
    }else{

        //translateImages();
        $('#turnGroup').stop().animate({
            svgTransform: 'translate('+(translationCompensationTurnX+position)+',0) scale('+scaleX+',1)'
        },0);

        turnIndex = 1;
        $('#turn'+turnIndex).show();

        $('#walk'+walkIndex).hide();


        if(!currentDirectionLeft && !directionToWalkLeft){
            console.log('finished walking and should turn');
           Element.prototype.turn();
        }else if (!animationCompleted){
            //completed and facing in the right direction:
            clearInterval(walkTimeout);
            directionToWalkLeft = true;
            console.log('Should show static position: '+translationCompensationTurnX+position+ '. '+ scaleX );
            animationCompleted= true;
            $('#slider').slider('enable');
        }

    }


}
//Init turn
Element.prototype.turn= function(){
    turnIndex=1;
    $('#turn'+turnIndex).show();
    clearInterval(walkTimeout);
    walkTimeout = setInterval(turn, 100);
}

function turn(){

    if(turnIndex<40){
        $('#turn'+turnIndex).hide();
        turnIndex = (turnIndex+1)%41+1;
        $('#turn'+turnIndex).show();

    }else{
        currentDirectionLeft =! currentDirectionLeft;
        clearInterval(walkTimeout);
        scaleX=scaleX*(-1);
        walk();
        walkTimeout = setInterval(walk, 100);

    }
}

function hideAll(){
    for(var i =1; i<41; i++){
        $('#walk'+i).hide();
        $('#turn'+i).hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not draw for me in Chrome or FF.

Comment: Yeah about that, it draws a box instead of the imported image. however the glitch can still be seen. Here is the original http://users.student.lth.se/et08dc0/svg/index_417.html

Comment: fiddle should draw better now...